# What is GPS and TR in EMTP RV?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-transmission

[image: One-line diagram of hybrid multi-terminal transmission systems (equipped with transient recorders and GPS signal receivers).]

I Want to simulate following system in EMTP RV but i dont have any idea what is GPS and TR(transiet recorder)

Answer (score 0):

The GPS signal is streamed at a 50Hz rate.

It is called NAV code. The TR (transient recorder) or receiver can read its position off these NAV codes.

Then it connects the dots and draws a course line on a background map application like google earth or shipping charts or aviation charts or the proprietary maps.

[NAV code source](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog862/node/1734)

> The entire Navigation message, the Master Frame, contains 25 frames. Each frame is 1500 bits long and is divided into five subframes. Each subframe contains 10 words and each word is comprised of 30 bits. Therefore, the entire Navigation message contains 37,500 bits and at a rate of 50 bits-per-second takes 12½ minutes to broadcast and to receive on a completely cold start. In other words, getting the whole thing is not instantaneous. It does take a bit of time for the receiver to update its Navigation Message.

Comment: thank u so much sir...could u tell me what element  should I use for them in EMTP?

Comment: Just to be clear, the receiver **does not** "read its position off these NAV codes" The message sent by each satellite provides the **satellite's** position and current GPS time. The receiver triangulates using the messages from at least three satellites to estimate the receiver's position.